# How to view stderr log only with journalctl?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

Please assume there's an app/script which prints a great deal of logging data to `stdout`. When something bad but expected happens within the script (exception handling), scripts reports an error to `stderr` and then continues doing what it was doing.

`systemd` for sure is capable to collect this data and put it into the `journal`:

```
# systemctl show sd_test.service | grep 'Standard[OE]'
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
```

My `sd_test.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=A Test Service simply printing to stdout and stderr

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/narunas/sd_test.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`journalctl` now has required data:

```
# systemctl reenable sd_test.service
# systemctl restart sd_test.service
# journalctl -n -u sd_test
-- Logs begin at Fri 2016-11-11 15:49:33 GMT, end at Tue 2017-01-03 19:23:18 GMT. --
Jan 03 19:23:01 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stderr": 2
Jan 03 19:23:02 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stdout": 2
Jan 03 19:23:03 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stderr": 3
Jan 03 19:23:07 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stdout": 3
Jan 03 19:23:07 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stderr": 4
Jan 03 19:23:11 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stdout": 4
Jan 03 19:23:12 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stderr": 5
Jan 03 19:23:15 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stdout": 5
Jan 03 19:23:17 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stdout": 6
Jan 03 19:23:18 dev-box sd_test.py[13183]: This is "stderr": 6
```

I know there's `_TRANSPORT` journal field, sadly `stderr` is tagged with the same tag:

> **stdout**
>       for those read from a service's standard output or error output

I can of course change my `ExecStart` like so:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/home/narunas/sd_test.py 2> /some/file/path'
```

But that is not ideal as I'm mixing up `journal` with files...

Could you recommend a better way to view `stderr` log only?

***EDIT_1***

As suggested in the comments I just tried `-o verbose` option:

```
Tue 2017-01-03 20:23:49.994171 GMT [s=0b15e5c69e2f476eb200d2bdda769465;i=12e28;b=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb;m=42e034d52dc;t=5453672322abb;x=8b696c5447bc2bce]
    PRIORITY=6
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=system.slice
    _BOOT_ID=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb
    _MACHINE_ID=c5a9e78e2c854065a9b041c58f07c2b2
    _HOSTNAME=dev-box
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
    _TRANSPORT=stdout
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=sd_test.py
    _COMM=python3
    _EXE=/usr/bin/python3.5
    _CMDLINE=python3 /home/narunas/sd_test.py
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/sd_test.service
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sd_test.service
    MESSAGE=This is "stdout": 729
    _PID=13183
Tue 2017-01-03 20:23:52.979981 GMT [s=0b15e5c69e2f476eb200d2bdda769465;i=12e29;b=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb;m=42e037ae22e;t=54536725fba0d;x=8802c0df56848907]
    PRIORITY=6
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=system.slice
    _BOOT_ID=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb
    _MACHINE_ID=c5a9e78e2c854065a9b041c58f07c2b2
    _HOSTNAME=dev-box
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
    _TRANSPORT=stdout
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=sd_test.py
    _COMM=python3
    _EXE=/usr/bin/python3.5
    _CMDLINE=python3 /home/narunas/sd_test.py
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/sd_test.service
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sd_test.service
    MESSAGE=This is "stderr": 745
    _PID=13183
```

`-o json-pretty` produce same results as `-o verbose`, but in a different format.

Apart my script's silly *MESSAGE* there's nothing useful that would let to distinguish what is `stderr` or `stdout`.

***EDIT_2***

With `StandardError=journal`.

*Unit*:

```
[Unit]
Description=A Test Service simply printing to stdout and stderr

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/narunas/sd_test.py
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*journalctl*:

```
# systemctl reenable sd_test.service
# systemctl restart sd_test.service
# journalctl -n -u sd_test -o verbose
Tue 2017-01-03 22:34:55.381341 GMT [s=0b15e5c69e2f476eb200d2bdda769465;i=13ab7;b=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb;m=42fd81d9b7e;t=545384702735d;x=e65570c85dfec1dc]
    _TRANSPORT=stdout
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=sd_test.py
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _COMM=python3
    _EXE=/usr/bin/python3.5
    _CMDLINE=python3 /home/narunas/sd_test.py
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/sd_test.service
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sd_test.service
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=system.slice
    _BOOT_ID=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb
    _MACHINE_ID=c5a9e78e2c854065a9b041c58f07c2b2
    _HOSTNAME=dev-box
    MESSAGE=This is "stdout": 10
    _PID=21280
Tue 2017-01-03 22:34:57.397880 GMT [s=0b15e5c69e2f476eb200d2bdda769465;i=13ab8;b=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb;m=42fd83c6099;t=5453847213878;x=610237e701d596d4]
    _TRANSPORT=stdout
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=sd_test.py
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _COMM=python3
    _EXE=/usr/bin/python3.5
    _CMDLINE=python3 /home/narunas/sd_test.py
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/sd_test.service
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sd_test.service
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=system.slice
    _BOOT_ID=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb
    _MACHINE_ID=c5a9e78e2c854065a9b041c58f07c2b2
    _HOSTNAME=dev-box
    MESSAGE=This is "stderr": 11
    _PID=21280
Tue 2017-01-03 22:35:02.403014 GMT [s=0b15e5c69e2f476eb200d2bdda769465;i=13abc;b=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb;m=42fd888bfe7;t=54538476d97c6;x=a6362820cb52ce9]
    _TRANSPORT=stdout
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=sd_test.py
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _COMM=python3
    _EXE=/usr/bin/python3.5
    _CMDLINE=python3 /home/narunas/sd_test.py
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/sd_test.service
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sd_test.service
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=system.slice
    _BOOT_ID=db55b41f61144ae69cc86acfb75209fb
    _MACHINE_ID=c5a9e78e2c854065a9b041c58f07c2b2
    _HOSTNAME=dev-box
    MESSAGE=This is "stderr": 12
    _PID=21280
```

Comment: Check `journalctl … -o verbose` or `-o json-pretty` to see if there is anything...

Comment: @derobert please see edited question.

Comment: Hmmm... Does setting `StandardError=journal` get the _TRANSPORT set to stderr?

Comment: @derobert Please see Edit_2

Comment: Hmm. As a last resort `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/narunas/sd_test.py | logger'` ought to get stdout to syslog, so it'll go to the journal with `_TRANSPORT=syslog` leaving stderr with `_TRANSPORT=stdout`. Confusing...

Comment: I just added a [feature request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5019).

Answer (score 3):

A [pull-request implementing the feature](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/6599) is currently under review.

In the meanwhile, if you control the script run with this unit, you may use the [python-systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/journal.html) module to send messages from your script to the journal with the priority and options you may wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you prepend your message with <*priority-level*> your message will be recorded in the journal with that priority. You can find a list with the levels, a brief description and some usage examples [at this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Journal).

Compiling this piece of code on my machine

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

const char* pri_msg[] {
    "EMERGENCY",
    "ALERT",
    "CRITICAL",
    "ERROR",
    "WARNING",
    "NOTICE",
    "INFO",
    "DEBUG"
};

int main(){
    int pri = 0;
    while(true) {
        std::printf("<%d>Test service priority level: %s", pri, pri_msg[pri]);
        pri = ++pri % 8;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }
}
```

and running it as a systemd service, each message is logged to journald with its priority level.

Then, you can retrieve them with `journalctl -u *your-service* -p *priority-level*`:

```
$ journalctl -u testd -p 3
-- Logs begin at mer 2020-10-21 17:31:13 CEST, end at ven 2020-10-23 16:01:01 CEST. --
ott 23 15:57:30 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: EMERGENCY
ott 23 15:57:35 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: ALERT
ott 23 15:57:40 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: CRITICAL
ott 23 15:57:45 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: ERROR
ott 23 15:58:10 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: EMERGENCY
ott 23 15:58:15 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: ALERT
ott 23 15:58:20 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: CRITICAL
ott 23 15:58:25 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: ERROR
ott 23 15:58:50 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: EMERGENCY
ott 23 15:58:55 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: ALERT
ott 23 15:59:00 legion testd[21967]: Test service priority level: CRITICAL
```

In your case I would just add a "`<3>`" behind every message logged with `std::cerr` (or `fprintf(stderr, ...)`.